# Cuando paso un objeto en el constructor

Tags: java, poo, objeto, constructor

Hola buenas mirad es que estoy creando un proyecto en Java sobre un catálogo de coches el cual se compone de tres archivos .java:

- Coche.java : Aquí pongo los atributos y métodos que debe de tener un objeto de la clase Coche

```
package catalogo;


public class Coche {

    public static int NUM_BASTIDOR = 00000000000;
    
    private String matricula;
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;
    private String generacion;
    private String defectos_encontrados;
    
    public Coche (String matricula, String marca, String modelo, Seguro billete) { //cuando paso un objeto billete de la clase Seguro
      this.matricula = matricula;
      this.marca = marca;
      this.modelo = modelo;
    }
    
    public String toString() { //aquí quiero que me imprima las propiedades del objeto que quiero imprimir también
    String resultado = "-------------------------------\n" +
    "Coche: " + this.matricula +"\n"+
    "Empleado id: " + this.marca + "\n"
    + "Nombre: "+ this.modelo + "\n" +
    "Nómina: " +Seguro.getNum() + "€\n" //esta es la línea que me falla
            + "Retención del "+Seguro.num_cotizacion+" ";
    return resultado;
}
}
```

- mainCat : este es el main del programa el cual declaro objetos Coche y Seguro:

```
 package catalogo;
    
    public class mainCat {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Seguro persona = new Seguro (1,34);
            Seguro persona2 = new Seguro (2, 33);
            
            Coche coche1 = new Coche ("4343mmm", "Opel", "Omega", persona);
            Coche coche2 = new Coche ("3324ooo", "Cadillac", "DeVille Touring Sedan", persona2);
        }
    }
```

- Seguro.java: aquí construyo la clase Seguro de la cual el constructor sólo tiene dos elementos

```
package catalogo;


public class Seguro {
    
    private int num_seguro;
    private float cotiz;
    
    public static float num_cotizacion=0;
    
    public Seguro (int num_seguro, float cotiz) {
        
        this.num_seguro = num_seguro;
        num_cotizacion++;
        this.cotiz = num_cotizacion;
    }
    
    public int getNum () { //aquí tengo el método getNum para obtener el número de seguro del billete de tal persona
        return num_seguro;
    }
}
```

Y bueno ahora que ya presenté los tres archivos el problema es que al pasar un objeto de la clase `Seguro` al constructor de `Coche` es que no sé como declararlo bien (ya que los de matricula, marca, modelo... lo hago con el `This`) pero al ser objeto no sé puff y luego cuando tengo el método de imprimir (`toString`) no sé como imprimir los detalles de ese objeto (Nómina y retencion) que intento recurrir al getNum para tener el num de seguro pero nada...

Si alguien puede ayudarme (porfa piedad que soy novato en Java xD) lo agradecería gracias!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te he corregido los errores y en los comentarios te he añadido los problemas que he visto. Si tienes alguna duda más no dudes en preguntar, por supuesto!

**Coche.java**

```
package catalogo;


public class Coche {

    public static int NUM_BASTIDOR = 0;//Esto deberías hacerlo privado también y hacer un getter para leerlo
    //La dejo en 0 porque un int 00000000000 es exactamente lo mismo que un int 0, si quieres más dígitos deberás hacerlo String

    private String matricula;
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;
    private String generacion;
    private String defectos_encontrados;
    private Seguro seguro; // Es un objeto... pero qué importa? Es una variable más! No te preocupes, solo decláralo

    public Coche(String matricula, String marca, String modelo, Seguro billete) { //cuando paso un objeto billete de la clase Seguro
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.seguro = billete;//Y asígnalo sin más, sabías que String es un Objeto también? Es lo mismo!
    }

    public String toString() { //aquí quiero que me imprima las propiedades del objeto que quiero imprimir también
        String resultado = "-------------------------------\n" +
                "Coche: " + this.matricula + "\n" +
                "Empleado id: " + this.marca + "\n"
                + "Nombre: " + this.modelo + "\n" +
                "Nómina: " + this.seguro.getNum() + "€\n" //Ahora ya no falla, accedes al objeto y a su método getNum()!
                + "Retención del " + Seguro.getNumCotizacion() + " ";/*Aquí accedemos a un método estático, en vez de la variable estática
                Es exactamente lo mismo que tener la variable pública, pero ahora si aquí quisiera hacer numCotizacion++ no podría.
                De esta manera tenemos protegido el valor de numCotizacion, ya que solo la clase Seguro podrá modificarla!*/
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

**Seguro.java**

```
package catalogo;


public class Seguro {

    private int numSeguro;//Las variables también deben seguir la notación CamelCase, pero con inicial en minúscula
    private float cotiz;

    private static float numCotizacion=0;//Si dejas esto público ten en cuenta que es accesible y modificable desde fuera!

    public Seguro (int num_seguro, float cotiz) {
        this.cotiz = cotiz; //Te faltaba asignar la cotización!
        this.numSeguro = num_seguro;
        numCotizacion++;
        this.cotiz = numCotizacion;
    }

    public int getNum () { //aquí tengo el método getNum para obtener el número de seguro del billete de tal persona
        return numSeguro;
    }

    public static float getNumCotizacion(){
        return numCotizacion;
    }
}
```

**MainCat.java**

```
package catalogo;

public class MainCat {//También he cambiado esto, en java las clases deben empezar por Mayúscula (CamelCase se llama a esta notación)

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Seguro persona = new Seguro (1,34);
        Seguro persona2 = new Seguro (2, 33);

        Coche coche1 = new Coche ("4343mmm", "Opel", "Omega", persona);
        Coche coche2 = new Coche ("3324ooo", "Cadillac", "DeVille Touring Sedan", persona2);
        System.out.println(coche1);
        System.out.println(coche2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!! Era eso entonces que no tenía declarado el objeto en el constructor de Coche y ahora ya puedo acceder a sus métodos sin ningún problema, muchas gracias y hasta la próxima!!!